# JQuery UI craziness

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am surely missing something easy as I am a relative noob at this.  Help is appreciated!  I am trying to get anything from the JQuery UI to work and nothing will.  JQuery and JQuery UI both load without errors.  But I can't seem to use any JQuery UI method successfully.  Here's the loads from the head of the page:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
```

Here's a jsfiddle as an example where I'm just trying to toggle a class on mouseenter.  http://jsfiddle.net/8WTaW/1/ 
What is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Next time, please include the code directly in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capitalize the 'c' in 'toggleclass' in your code. Javascript is a case-sensitive language, and thus the proper method invocation will be 'toggleClass':

```
$(function () {
    $('.navs').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('navshover');
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: Thank you! <Head slap heard around the world>

Answer (score 2):

Capital "C".

It's

```
$(this).toggleClass('navshover');
```

not

```
$(this).toggleclass('navshover');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8WTaW/2/)**

(and note, you don't need jQueryUI for this particular example.)